# What is getrealpath and how to upload the image?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

[image: homecontroller.java]

What is realpath? And what is the meaning of this code?

Comment: Please upload code as text, not images. Would you repair this please, by editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

An application server maps relative paths that you specify to a absolute path, for your use. Where exactly that path is, depends on the application server you are using. Check the documentation of the app server you are using to see where the root of all relative paths will be placed.